# How do I display the meaningful values in a partially filled array?

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone help me with this i'm just confused!!
Suppose arr is an array of values of type double that is partially filled.  The array contains meaningful values in only the first numberUsed elements, where numberUsed is a variable of type int.  Write code to display all the meaningful values in the array arr.

Comment: Use a `List`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: We do not do your homework. Please show us your what you have done so far.

Comment: Please let us know the code you tried to help.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, he is going off of a request from a teacher I would assume, this is a basic level programming question that I believe he is looking to answer.

Comment: @liquidsystem then that should be **stated clearly in the question**. As it stands _use a `List`_ is the only correct answer.

Comment: You do not need a `List` to display all of the variables. He gives you what the list goes up to, and you can create a For-Loop from that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( int i = 0; i < numberUsed; i++ )
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

But for future reference, please supply code that you have tried, and do not just come here for someone to do your homework.

Comment: Right, but you should have an understanding of this if it is for a class, if not, maybe pay closer attention. What I said above would do what you asked for.

Comment: I do have an understading of it. I was just thinking way to hard about the question. But literaly it just hit me. So thank you! I'm just studying btw this isn't for hw.

Comment: Alright, well if this was the answer you were looking for, you can select it as the correct answer so others don't spend time on it.